# yarn says "pattern is trying to unpack in the same destination"

Tags: git, npm, yarnpkg

I have two submodules sourced via `yarn` using git URL:s

- `foo`, which exists in version `0.5.38`, and which has a dependency to `bar: ^0.5`
- `bar`, which exists in version `0.5.1`

My `app` package.json:

```
foo: git+ssh://git@github.com:myorg/foo#semver:0.5.38,
bar: git+ssh://git@github.com:myorg/bar#semver:0.5.1,
```

When building this, I get:

```
warning Pattern ["bar@git+ssh://git@github.com:myorg/bar.git#semver:^0.5"] is trying to unpack in the 
same destination "~/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-bar-0.5.1-344cefa6f7681a6a15e52adbff65cbaf6cf67318/node_modules/bar" 
as pattern ["bar@git+ssh://git@github.myorg/bar.git#semver:0.5.1"]. 
This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
```

What does this mean? Is my configuration incorrect in any way? All I want is that `foo` uses `bar @ 0.5.x`, and `app` uses `foo @ 0.5.38` and `bar @ 0.5.1`, which should be compatible, right?